# Minimum spanning tree formulation

Tags: graph-theory

I'm writing up a report for a solution of an energy grid problem for school, and after reading the CS-book multiple times (and a bit of googling), I can't seem to find the mathematical definition of the MST-problem. Is this correct?

Problem: Given an undirected weighted graph $G(V,E, w)$, $\text{vertex set } V$, $\text{edge set } E$, $w$ an edge weight function $w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{+}}$, produce a subgraph $H(V^{*},E^{*})$, without cycles, such that the cost function $C: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{+}}$, $C(E)=\sum_{e \in E}{f(e)}$ is minimal (i.e. the smallest possible scalar value among all constructible spanning trees).

Comment: H(V,E*), E* is a subset of E, H is a tree, this means no cycles but als that it is connected, otherwise H(V,0) would be a solution. And C(E*) should be minimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition is almost correct, just that the graph should be spanning, that is, $V=V^*$ and that $H$ should be connected, trivially.

Comment: and it should be connected

Comment: @miracle173 thanks! edited the post

Comment: Thank you. Would have upvoted if I could have.

Comment: @EdwinCarlsson you can accept the answer even if you cant upvote it